# Changing the Ruby Font (for Pīnyīn)

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, cjk

Using `ruby` package to generate both furigana for Japanese and Pīnyīn for Chinese.  I use individual `\sf` calls to individually switch each Pīnyīn from the Japanese font back to the default sans font.  Is there an easier way?

(I should clarify that I understand each CJK font has roman glyphs for Pīnyīn, but I *prefer* the Biolinum.)

Please see MWE...its output makes my question more clear, I think:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% PACKAGES

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Libertine Mono O}
\usepackage{ruby}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document} % ==============================================================

\newfontfamily{\J}[Scale=0.85]{Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro}
\newfontfamily{\C}{STKaiti}

\doublespace
\Large

I'd like to include both Chinese (e.g. {\C\renewcommand\rubysep{-4.9ex}\ruby{内}{\sf nèi}\ruby{忧}{\sf yōu}\ruby{外}{\sf wǎi}\ruby{患}{\sf huàn}}) and Japanese (e.g. {\J\renewcommand\rubysep{-1.9ex}\ruby{内}{ない}\ruby{憂}{ゆう}\ruby{外}{がい}\ruby{患}{かん}}) text, \textit{inline} with English text, and with ruby text (pronunciation), as shown here.  Does there exist a convenient method for distributing the \texttt{\textbackslash sf} (or preferably \texttt{\textbackslash textsf\{\}}), across all the \texttt{\textbackslash ruby} calls to generate the Pīnyīn (the text below the Chinese)?

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can define a new command with all the necessary parameters, in your case something like `\newcommand{\HanZi}[2]{\ruby{#1}{\sf #2}}`. Your text will be more readable: `"... Chinese (e.g. {\C\renewcommand\rubysep{-4.9ex}\HanZi{内}{nèi}, \HanZi{忧}{yōu}, ...} ..."`. Also you can think of new commands to setup chinese and japanese ruby... The `pinyin` package may be helpful also.

Comment: While I RTFM on that, would you mind quickly answering:  is there a way to permit an arbitrary number of (paired) arguments, so that my command might look like `\HanZi{同}{tóng}{治}{zhì}{中}{zhōng}{興}{xīng}...`?  (Though it occurs to me that if such a thing were possible, `ruby`'s authors would have implemented it.)  (Also, I'm avoiding the `pinyin` package for the moment, since my Chinese text will be minimal, and I intend to exert positive control over each Pīnyīn anyway.)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know any way to handle an arbitrary number of arguments, let alone forcing an even number of them. That's unfortunate, because I like your idea a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this to see if it breaks anything, but it seems creating some new commands that pass their arguments to `\ruby{}{}` might work. This allows you to renew the `\rubysep` every time as well as apply `\textsf` only to the Pīnyīn. The example should make things clear.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% PACKAGES

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Libertine Mono O}
\usepackage{ruby}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document} % ==============================================================

\newfontfamily{\jpn}[Scale=0.85]{Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro}
\newcommand{\J}[2]{\renewcommand\rubysep{-1.9ex}{\jpn \ruby{#1}{#2}}}

\newfontfamily{\chn}{STKaiti}
\newcommand{\C}[2]{\renewcommand\rubysep{-4.9ex}{\chn \ruby{#1}{\textsf{#2}}}}

\doublespace
\Large

I'd like to include both Chinese (e.g. \C{内}{nèi}\C{忧}{yōu}\C{外}{wǎi}\C{患}{huàn}) and Japanese (e.g. \J{内}{ない}\J{憂}{ゆう}\J{外}{がい}\J{患}{かん}) text, \textit{inline} with English text, and with ruby text (pronunciation), as shown here.  Does there exist a convenient method for distributing the \texttt{\textbackslash sf} (or preferably \texttt{\textbackslash textsf\{\}}), across all the \texttt{\textbackslash ruby} calls to generate the Pīnyīn (the text below the Chinese)?

\end{document}
```

Note: I removed `xunicode` from the header because it's automatically loaded by `fontspec`.